# Handler for <turbo-frame>-related errors that displays custom error messages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, turbo-frames

I'm using Rails 7 and am thinking of implementing a handler for [turbo frame](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/)-related errors that displays custom error messages. For example, I would like to display *An error occurred, try later* instead of the default *Content missing* message, maybe associating error messages with HTTP statuses and handling this in one place and globally via JS.

Any insight about? For example, where (i.e. in which file e.g. app/javascript/application.js) and how (e.g. using addEventListener(), [turbo:frame-missing](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events) event, [custom actions](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#custom-actions)) should I make that?

---

In the meantime, I found [this](https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/best-patterns-and-practices-for-error-handling/3544).